# SQL Server Sort varchar columns depend on numbers inside like int and decimal

Tags: sql-server

Hello looking solution to sort sizes inside my column.
Exmaple :

```
-- CREATE TEMP TABLE 
Create Table #MyTempTable (
    size varchar(20)
);

-- insert sample data to TEMP TABLE 
insert into #MyTempTable
values 
('10.5W'),
('10W'),
('11.5W'),
('11W'),
('12W'),
('5.5W'),
('5W'),
('6.5W'),
('6W'),
('7.5W'),
('7W'),
('8.5W'),
('8W'),
('9.5W'),
('9W'),
('4')


select 'BEFORE',* from #MyTempTable


SELECT 'AFTER',size 
FROM #MyTempTable 
ORDER BY LEN(size)
```

When i order by LEN there is no good sorting like this :

```
AFTER   5W
AFTER   6W
AFTER   7W
AFTER   8W
AFTER   9W
AFTER   10W
AFTER   11W
AFTER   12W
AFTER   5.5W
AFTER   7.5W
AFTER   6.5W
AFTER   9.5W
AFTER   8.5W
AFTER   10.5W
AFTER   11.5W
```

All im' looking for is to sort in proper order. like this :

```
5W
5.5W
6W
6.5W
7W
7.5W
8W
8.5W
9W
9.5W
10W
10.5W
11W
11.5W
12W
```

I seearched a lot of stackoverflow and can't find solution for that because there is not only int and also decimal numbers. So don't know how to get it

Comment: Seems like the real problem is the design, if you want to sort data numerically *store* it in a numerical data type. Your values `5` and `'W'` should be in different columns here.

Comment: You added `4` to the sample data (because solutions generated an error), but you didn't indicate where you want it to sort (we don't know what "proper order" is for you when you have mixed data). Please try to include _all_ edge cases in your sample data from the beginning, because if you don't, people won't know about them and will waste time producing invalid or incomplete solutions. Are there other formats, for example? Any other letter suffixes _other than_ W?

Comment: Another edge case to consider - can any suffixes be more than one character? Can't a shoe size be `11.5DD` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of other options:

```
-- if you don't know all of the potential non-numeric characters:

SELECT size FROM #MyTempTable
  ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,2), 
    SUBSTRING(size,1,COALESCE(NULLIF
        (PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', size),0),255)-1));

-- if there is a finite set (say, W and D):

DECLARE @KnownChars varchar(32) = 'WD';

SELECT size FROM #MyTempTable
  ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,2), 
    TRANSLATE(size, @KnownChars, REPLICATE(space(1), LEN(@KnownChars))));
```

Comment: best anwear . thanks exacly what i was looking for

Comment: @Michael The best thing to do would be to store the number and letter suffix in 2 separate columns.  None of the answerd given here will perform terribly well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each value would always end in just one unit, you may sort on the numeric portion cast to a decimal:

```sql
SELECT size 
FROM #MyTempTable 
ORDER BY CAST(
    CASE WHEN size LIKE '%[A-Z]'
         THEN LEFT(size, LEN(size) - 1)
         ELSE size END AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 103 Error converting data type varchar to numeric. , there is a 4 at the end i edited later example just so this way is bad.

Comment: Then sort with a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

In `order by` clause first remove `W` from then cast as NUMERIC data type. Now you can expect sorting like a number.

```
SELECT *
FROM #MyTempTable AS mtt
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(mtt.size, LEN(mtt.size) - 1) AS DECIMAL) ASC;
```

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 103
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.  , there is a 4 at the end i edited later example just so this way is bad.

Comment: @Michael I have test my query with your create and insert statement in question before posting it. Did you write it yourself? compare with my answer again.

Comment: @Michael It seems your real data does not have same format. My answer has been written assuming all value are %w. If not then follow Tim's answer.